# Agent field not being populated in Jenkins Pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to investigate [Jenkins build time by node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64334002/42473) I noticed that when we switched to using [jenkins-timeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-timeline) our jobs stopped filling in the "Agent" field on the "Build Time Trend" page.

Old pre-pipeline jobs show the agent name in that list, but new pipeline jobs just show a blank agent field.

If I go into an individual pipeline build, I can look in the Console Output and find the `Running on` line to work out which agent was used, just as I can see the `Building remotely on` line in the console output of non pipeline builds.

Is there a way to get pipeline builds to fill in the Agent field with the machine the job was actually run on?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Jenkins does not collect this information when running Pipeline jobs, as Pipeline job may run on many agents in parallel.

We wanted to have that information so we run an instance of InfluxDB and send metrics there. These metrics include the agent name, so this is available for analysis later.